# somthing's wrong with django messages

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view function like this:

```
@login_required
def delete_deal(request, id_deal):
    id_deal = int(id_deal)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, id=request.user.id)
    user_deals = Deal.objects.filter(user=user)
    if not user_deals.exists():
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,
                                        'You have no deal.')

        return redirect('index')

    return render(request, 'booking/confirmation_delete.html', {'title': title})
```

If I test with a user who does not have a deal the message is not displayed the first time but if I redo the message is displayed 2 times, what is wrong ?

I have another view function which returns a message and it displays it normally !!

If you need more info tell me

**Update**:

Here is my url.py of the application where the view function above is located:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^create_deal/$', views.create_deal, name='create_deal'),
    url(r'^delete_deal/(?P<id_deal>[0-9]+)/$', views.delete_deal, name='delete_deal'),
]
```

The view.py function:

```
def index(request):
    all_deals = Deal.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'base.html', locals())
```

template.html:

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for message in messages %}
      <div>{{ message }}</div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue because to display the message I tried to enter in the search bar an url towards a deal which does not exist, and looking in the console I saw that passing the url in the search bar the view is executed before even hitting enter

My url was something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/booking/delete_deal/65/
```

and the number `65` is an id_deal which does not exist

I tried to add a link that redirect to the view function with an `id_deal` which does not exist and the message is always shown

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it adds the message both times and will redirect to 'index' both times... So perhaps the problem is either in the urls and view for 'index' or somehow in the template being rendered. Show us the urls.py, the associated view function/opject and template.